# Android automatic Bluetooth connection

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

When I turn on Bluetooth on my Android device and my Bluetooth speaker is in range, the phone automatically connects to the speaker, without me doing anything other that turning on Bluetooth.

I want to be able to do this with a Bluetooth module I am using in my Arduino Project. I wasn't able to find anything on that topic, but if my Chinese speaker does it, surely there must be a way mimic this behaviour.

My project involves Arduino, HC-05 module, and an android app. For now the connection is initiated with a button click inside the app. Is there a way to auto connect to the module before even starting an app? You connect to it, just by turning on Bluetooth on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Record the physical address of your peripheral and start a connection each time you discover that particual address. Programatically, that's all you can do. Else, you would have to do it manually from your Bluetooth settings.

Comment: This means I would have to have a thread running in the background scanning for devices every few seconds?

Comment: Yes. The only way you can replicate what normally happens with bluetooth devices and autoconnections is to manually connect from you Bluetooth settings.

Comment: But how does my speaker do it; or my car? it connects automatically when I sit into it with my Bluetooth on. Without any app running in the background.